# javascript/jquery start button for .ogg looped play

Tags: javascript, jquery, ogg

The code below generates and loops a randomized number of iterations of some .ogg files. They play as soon as the page loads.

The commented-out bits are my attempt to add a 'start' button. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I start this with a button rather than on page load?

(Also: I am suspecting that it is bad practice to combine php and javascript as I have done. I did it because randomization in php is so easy, and I am still new to js/jquery.)

(EDIT: see the edit below. I just forgot to close the tag.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Audio Testing</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php  
$randC = rand(2,4); 
$C = $randC * 4;
$G = $C / 2;
    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
        //    $(\"#start\").click(function() 
        //    { 
                var time = 0;
                var riff_time = 2920;
                var base = 'riff';
                for(i = 0; i < $C; i++)
                {
                    var id = base + ((i + 1) ); 
                    window.setTimeout (\"document.getElementById('\" + id + \"').play()\", time);
                    time += riff_time;
                }

                var timeG = 0;
                var riff_time = 2920;
                var baseG = 'riffG';
                for(iG = 0; iG < $G; iG++)
                {
                    var idG = baseG + ((iG + 1) );  
                    window.setTimeout (\"document.getElementById('\" + idG + \"').play()\", timeG);
                    timeG += riff_time;
        //      }               
              }       // EDIT: This should be }); ... that fixes it.    
            }); 
        </script>
        "?>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head> 

    <body style="background-color: #999;">

<!--<button id="start">Start</button>
    <br>  -->

    <?php
    echo "C:<br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<= $C; $i++) {
        echo '<audio controls id="riff'.$i.'">
        <source src="loopC.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>';
    }
    echo "<br>G:<br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<= $G; $i++) {
        echo '<audio controls id="riffG'.$i.'">
        <source src="loopG.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>';
    }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class `start` as well as and `data-id` to the start buttons.

So your html for start button would be like,

```
<img src="start-button.jpg" class="start" data-id="riff1"> 
            //So this is start button for audio elementwith id riff1.
```

How will this work?

```
$('.start').click(function(){
      $("#"+$(this).data('id')).play(); //This should do.
 }
```

And yes in your php file should be type of this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Audio Testing</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php  
$randC = rand(2,4); 
$C = $randC * 4;
$G = $C / 2;

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
        //    $("#start").click(function() 
        //    { 
                var time = 0;
                var riff_time = 2920;
                var base = 'riff';
 <?php      for(i = 0; i < $C; i++)
                {
                 echo "   var id = base + ((i + 1) ); 
                    window.setTimeout (\"document.getElementById('\" + id + \"').play()\", time);
                    time += riff_time; ";
                }
    ?>
                var timeG = 0;
                var riff_time = 2920;
                var baseG = 'riffG';
     <?php           for(iG = 0; iG < $G; iG++)
                {
                 echo "   var idG = baseG + ((iG + 1) );  
                    window.setTimeout (\"document.getElementById('\" + idG + \"').play()\", timeG);
                    timeG += riff_time;   ";
        //      }       ?>        
              } 
            }); 
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head> 

    <body style="background-color: #999;">

<!--<button id="start">Start</button>
    <br>  -->

    <?php
    echo "C:<br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<= $C; $i++) {
        echo '<audio controls id="riff'.$i.'">
        <source src="loopC.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>';
    }
    echo "<br>G:<br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<= $G; $i++) {
        echo '<audio controls id="riffG'.$i.'">
        <source src="loopG.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>';
    }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry to say, I'm not making this work. perhaps if you showed me the final code with your modifications? (also, I have no start-button.jpg image -  is there some reason not to use `<button class="start" data-id="riff1">`?

Comment: @GregoryTippett Thats not good. I cannot show you my final code. I could help you if you make a fiddle, with three audio files. And if you don't have start-button.jpg, can't you change the src to your image name here? It was an example. And using data-id would let you know id of the audio, that this start button is attached to. Make a fiddle, with three audio files and I will show you.

Comment: you mean http://jsfiddle.net/ ? ... it won't run php. Any audio files will do to test it, actually - it doesn't matter if it sounds the same, just if it starts with the button. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @GregoryTippett, I mean jsfiddle.net, it doesn't run php, but I just wanted you to add three audio elements, and jquery, (which jsfiddle would ofcourse run), then you could do the same for any number of audio you have.

Comment: If you want me to show you, i will prepare the fiddle if you face any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help with this code. It actually turns out to be a punctuation error. The code before the closing script tag currently reads: `} }); </script>`  , but it should read `}); }); </script>`

Comment: Okay, whatever works for you. If you think this was the answer to your question, mark as accepted.